# Is it OK to use single app registration for both end user log in and backend resource access? (as both public & confidential app)

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have an app registration X and I want user to log in through X to my service with implicit grant flow (as public application) and also have backend server use cert to auth with X and do client credentials flow to access internal storage(as confidential app).

In this case I am reuse the same app X for both purposes. Is it a good practice or is there any concern in terms of security of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same application to access different services. As you said, you want to use a single application to register for end user login and back-end resource access. It is possible at this time, but for security reasons, you need to serve different projects. Create different client secrets (in your question you need to create two client secrets for the application).

Just be aware of the caveats, eg, if you have only one app registration, in the enterprise app, you can only set one set of users, so if for example you want to control who has access to one of the apps but not the other. you cant do that through the enterprise application registration. so you would have to do it through your own code.Please see:[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps).

So, in summary, I suggest that you create different applications for different projects, which is easier to manage.